# How to perform transformations on list/array of tuples in spark scala RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a list of tuples - How can I perform reduce on integer values of each tuple?

```
val student=List((1,"akshay",60),(2,"salman",70),(3,"ranveer",50))
val student_rdd=sc.parallelize(student)
rdd1.reduce((a,b)=>(a._3+b._3)).collect

error: type mismatch;
found: Int
required: (Int, String, Int)
```

Comment: What do you want to happen to the first and second columns?

E.g. (1, "akshay", 60) and (2, "salman", 70) should become (X, Y, 130).
What do you want X and Y to be there?

Comment: Are you just looking for the total of all the values in column 3?

Comment: I want to calculate sum,min,max,avg of last value in tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are much better ways than using RDDs, but if you want to get sum, min, max, avg in one pass using reduce then this would work

```scala
val res = {
  val a = student_rdd.map(r => (r._3, r._3, r._3, 1))
    .reduce((a, b) => (a._1 + b._1, Math.min(a._2, b._2), 
      Math.max(a._3, b._3), a._4 + b._4))
  a.copy(_4 = a._1 * 1.0 / a._4)
}
```

This gives you a tuple with (sum, min, max, avg)

Answer (score 2):

You can map the values before reducing. The other columns are not necessary for the reduction and should be removed before reduction.

```
student_rdd.map(_._3).reduce(_+_)
```

Comment: your solution works for sum only, what if I want min and max?

Comment: then use `_ min _` or `_ max _` inside `reduce`

Comment: student_rdd.map(_._3).reduce(_min_) - > error: not found: value _min_

Comment: you need a space between `_` and `min`